# Search Engine for a blog_website(searching inside links )

Tags: search-engine, blogs, code-search-engine

I created a very basic search option for my blog, and as per topics and key words it is generating results but what i am looking for is in certain articles i have to add links so if my search can go through those links that are basically external websites for example if i am referring to someone else blog for more information then search to find from that.Is it possible ? And i don't want to go for GCSE. 
Thanks in advance. It will be of great help.

Thanks again.

Comment: Could you please edit your Q so that it doesn't read as 1 long run-on sentence? Also, would you please clarify what the acronym GCSE is? I haven't seen that acronym before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to write a bot to crawl external websites from links. I've made one. It crawled 100K+ website URLs. So yes, it is possible to make one, which can crawl links from your blog.

To create a search engine, you'll need to know some internals regarding how they work...

**Search Bots** work like this:

1. **Crawler** fetches pages. This step is pretty easy, as it uses [curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL).
2. **Parser** splits the HTML into pieces, so that data can be extracted from the page. This has 2 sub-components to it, which...

   a. Extracts any data from the page that you want to capture & then saves that data into a database.

   b. Extracts links & places them back into the crawling queue. This creates an infinite loop, so your bot never stops crawling... (Unless someone else's malformed URL crashes it, which happens a lot. So be ready to frequently fix it.)
3. **Indexer** creates lookup indexes, which map keywords to the web page's contents. This has 2 sub-components to it, as it...

   a. Creates a [Forward Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_indexing#The_forward_index), which maps each document to keywords that are inside of that document.

   ```
   doc1 | bird, aviary, robin, dove, blue jay, cardinal
   doc2 | birds, bird watching, binoculars
   doc3 | cats, eat, birds
   doc4 | cats, generally, don't, like, water, nor, neighborhood, dogs
   doc5 | dog, shows, look, fun
   ```

   b. Creates an [Inverted Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) from the Forward Index, which reverses the indices. This allows users to search by keyword & then the search script looks up & suggests which documents, that users may want to view. Like so...

   ```
   bird | doc1, doc2
   cat  | doc3, doc4
   dog  | doc4, doc5
   ```

**Search Forms** work like this:

1. Search **Form** shows the HTML input box to the user.
2. Search **Script** will search the Inverted Index to find which document links to display in the Search Engine Results Page.
3. **S**earch **E**ngine **R**esults **P**age (yes, SERP is an actual industry acronym for Search Engine Results Page). This displays the list of search result links. You can style it any way that you'd like & it doesn't have to look like Google's, Microsoft's Bing nor Yahoo's engines.

**Examples:**

Searching for:

```
"bird" returns links to "doc1, doc2"
"cat"  returns links to "doc3, doc4"
"dog"  returns links to "doc4, doc5"
```

Good luck building your search engine for your blog!

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer,I will work on it and definitely am coming back with more doubts :)